# Writing an AWK instruction in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

In a bash script, I need to do this:

```
cat<<EOF> ins.exe
grep 'pattern' file | awk '{print $2}' > results
EOF
```

The problem is that $2 is interpreted as a variable and the file ins.exe ends up containing 
"grep 'pattern' file | awk '{print }' > results", without the $2.

I've tried using

```
echo "grep 'pattern' file | awk '{print $2}' > results" >> ins.exe
```

But it's the same problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `awk '{print \$2}'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the `$`:

```
cat<<EOF> ins.exe
awk '/pattern/ { print \$2 }' file > results
EOF
```

No need to pipe grep to awk, by the way.

With bash, you have another option as well, which is to use `<<'EOF'`. This means that no expansions will occur within the string.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer!